# determine length of calloc array of TCHARs (not string length)

Tags: c, calloc

I have this code:

```
TCHAR *sRes;
sRes = (TCHAR *) calloc(16384, sizeof(TCHAR));
DWORD dwRes = sizeof(sRes);
```

dwRes is always 8, and of course _tcslen(sRes) is always 0.

I am looking for 16384.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported mechanism for obtaining size of a block allocated with malloc or calloc. If you call `HeapAlloc` instead you may call `HeapSize` thereafter.

Comment: I read HeapAlooc will get the memory from the process default heap. calloc will get the memory from CRT heap. What's the implications of usage of either one?

Comment: You to free HeapAlloc memory with HeapFree. I also suspect that it's slower, but it's been a long time.

Answer (score 3):

In C there is no way to get the size of a memory block with only the base address of the block.

But when you created the block, you knew the size: just save it and use it afterwards when you need:

```
TCHAR *sRes;
DWORD dwRes = 16384 * sizeof (TCHAR);
sRes = calloc(16384, sizeof (TCHAR)); /* I prefer `sizeof *sRes` */

/* use `sRes` and `dwRes` as needed ... */
```

Also, notice I removed the cast from the return value of `calloc`. Casting here serves no useful purpose and may hide an error.

Comment: But I get a compiler error if I don't cast it.

Comment: Then you're probably compiling with a C++ compiler. I prefer to use C compilers for C code, but I understand some people like to compile C code with C++ compilers for extra (*redundant and possibly erroneous*) diagnostics.

Comment: Yes, I am compiling with a C++ compiler. 
@Blagovest: I'm using Visual Studio 2008. I get a "void *" compiler error.

Comment: Using a C++ compiler for C code is like [speaking British english in the USA or vice-versa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Words_and_phrases_with_different_meanings). Do it at your own risk. I think it is possible to configure Visual Studio as a C (C89) compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system and the underlying memory allocator implementation keep track of that number, but there is no standard facility to obtain this value in application code.

`sizeof` is a static operator and hence cannot be used to return the size of anything that's determined at runtime.

Your only option is to create a custom struct where you manually keep both the returned pointer and the size which was allocated.